# php associative array: no array build with key from variable name

Tags: php, simplexml

this code works as expected

```
$fruits = array("d" => "Zitrone", "b" => "Banane", "c" => "Apfel");
$fruits["a"] = "Orange";
//print_r($fruits);
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

ok, now I would like to do the same programmatically:

```
$collection = array();
foreach ($xml->abschnitte[0]->abschnitt as $sec) {
    //echo $sec['strecke']; // this works, the strings are printed out
    $collection[$sec['strecke']] = $sec['id'];
}
//print_r($collection);  // nothing to see here
//ksort($collection);
foreach ($collection as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . " = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

it seems that there no collection will be build. but there must be a way to build the key up from variables. what do i miss? thanks in advance, mischl

Comment: What you've written should work.

Comment: It sounds like a variable scope problem. Is any of this code in a function?

Comment: no. after the start of a php file, befor there is only:
`$xmlfile = "xyz";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlfile) or die("Error: Cannot create object");`

Comment: Can you add a simple XML file that demonstrates the problem, so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Does it work if you cast `$sec['strecke']` to string when setting it like this: `$collection[(string)$sec['strecke']] = $sec['id'];`?  SimpleXML objects can behave differently depending on context.

Comment: yes! cast to string was the solution! many thanks to all for their help, much appreciated it